# Can't use remote desktop to restart the server Windows server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

I have a windows server 2016 that I can't access through RD... I usually can but it's for some reason I get stuck on "Securing remote connection" 
https://support.microsoft.com/sv-se/kb/2915774

I want to restart the server computer, the server is up and running, and the website too. How can I restart it with for example RD credentials?

Comment: What's the purpose of including the link that appears to solve your problem but posting a question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PSExec to issue a remote shutdown with the proper argument to restart the server.

You can download PSExec from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it through another way :D